# Title href opens in iframe but img href not JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a post before and I didnt manage to fix it but here is a codepen with my problem so maybe someone out there know the problem

Here is the codepen:
"https://codepen.io/Lossmann/pen/GRrXyQY"

Comment: what error are you getting/ what exactly isnt happening?

Comment: the href from the a tag with the classname title comes in to the iframe shwoing the whole websate in the iframe but clickingthe image with the same href doesnt open in the iframe

Comment: so when you click the a tag you want the link to open just in the iframe instead of a whole new page opening?

Comment: exactly, only the a tag for the text works but not the image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I have solved it for
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/udabasili/pen/jOyvZNq?editors=0000)

This is just the snippet so click on the link above

```
const title = document.querySelector(".title")
const image = document.querySelector(".image img")

 title.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('a[href]')) {
      event.preventDefault()
      let url = event.target.getAttribute('href')
      document.getElementById('post').src = url

    }
  })
  image.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          let url = event.target.parentNode
          url =  url.getAttribute('href')
   document.getElementById('post').src = url
  })
```

The main issue was that you needed to the click event function to the image not the a tag with class named image. I also changed the querySelectorAll to querySelector since you only have one instance of the classes. But if there are multiple you can change it back. Also added styling for the image class to cover the full image since it wasnt doint that before

Comment: why the negative vote?

Comment: omg it worked, I have been on this for 2 days and shown everyone at work, firends etc and no one knew. All said it should work but you my friend made it work! Thank you so much!